# Mongo Compass does not display the number and size of collections

Tags: mongodb, compass

after inserting the documents in collections we cannot see the number and size of documents in mongo compass and it shows just 0 under Documents and Size of collection names.
However in Mongo shell or Mongoose we can see the count of documents when querying the collections.

Comment: You may want to refresh the Compass GUI (there are refresh buttons) and see the updates.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.